# Job offer Purchasing manager

Tags: united-states, scams, germany, job-offer

Been talking with a lady from Germany that wants me to be a purchasing manager. Here is the info I got

This work-at-home position is responsible for generation of purchase orders using Company's money, compiling reports, preparing shipments, and other as designated administrative duties. Base salary will be $98,400.00 per year ($8,200.00 monthly) plus commission. Commission will be from 10% up to 15% of a purchase amount for every fulfilled assignment. Benefits includes Medical, Dental, Vision, 401k, and Life Insurance.
Your main responsibilities include: communicating with vendors regarding products and prices, product availability, service, quality and other related issues; communicating with your Supervisor regarding vendor information as stated above; determining appropriate methods for product purchasing (from local stores/vendors or from online sites), if not previously designated by the Company; prepare and process purchase orders; prepare all designated reports; place orders on timely basis and insure on-time delivery.
You will responsible for the work designated by your personal Supervisor. You will not be required to relocate. There will be no long-distance trip requirements. Most of the work can be accomplished from home. Also, you will not be required to make any investment nor financial expense.

Does this sound like a scam to you? I really want a legit job,but kinda sounds to good to be true. What's your opinion?

Comment: Welcome new user.  It's just a well-known very common scam.

Comment: How have you "been talking" to the lady? Usually for job offers the communication channel alone can give the scam away.

Comment: Dror me it looks like scam. You normally get not such a commission as a purchasing manger

Answer (score 18):

This is scam. No one offers commission for a purchase manager.

Once you start communicating there are different ways this will proceed. All of them you will lose money

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is a scam. Most likely, it involves either helping them transport stolen merchandise (a so-called reshipping scam), laundering money, or utilizing stolen credit cards.

The pay structure they're offering is both highly unusual for a legitimate purchasing agent job (no one pays commission for that kind of a job) and far above the average salary for a first-time purchasing agent.
According to [salary.com](https://www.salary.com/research/salary/benchmark/purchasing-agent-salary), for example, the median salary for a purchasing agent in the United States is $65,211 per year. The average starting salary seems to be closer to $53,000. The quoted salary is simply too good to be true.

Offering commission based on the purchase price would be directly contrary to the company's best interest because it would give the agent a perverse incentive to get bad deals and punish agents who got good deals. For example, if a purchase agent who was receiving commission negotiated for a 10% better price on a transaction, they would also be cutting their own commission by 10%.

The fact that they explicitly point out that you'll be spending company money and that no personal expense or investment is involved is further proof. This is a given for *any* legitimate job; the fact that they point it out is in and of itself highly suspicious.

In fact, a well-run organization won't even allow personal funds to be "mixed" with organizational funds, as it creates an opportunity for embezzlement. I recall an instance in a non-profit I was involved in where someone had used a personal Paypal account to collect conference registration fees; while there's no evidence that any actual theft happened in that case, they got slapped around on their next audit for even taking that chance (and, for that matter, putting the individual in question in a position where they could come under suspicion for that). There was subsequently a very tense meeting about the organization's finances. (In fact, a close friend of mine worked at an organization where [commingling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commingling) personal funds and business funds actually did result in embezzlement of a substantial amount of money).

Answer (score 0):

## **rule of thumb: if it's too good to be true - it's illegal (or a scam).**

If you wish to be sure that this is a scam, you can do the followings:

1. What's their site looks like? Does it have http**s**?
2. Did she communicated with you via the email from the site above? Did you respond to her and get a reply back (again, from the same email)?
3. Did she contacted you directly (if yes - level of suspicious goes up high)

Usually, those kind of offers are provided **as a last stage of negotiations**.

Sounds like a classic 101 scam.

Comment: https is meaningless in this context. It's trivial for anyone to implement it anonymously and for free these days.